# Command T to open file in previously opened buffer

Tags: vim, split

I'm using Janus MacVim by Carlhuda, and I wonder if there's a way to tweak Command-T to open a file (buffer) only once, instead of into multiple splits of the same buffer.

Eg:  Assumming your directory/project has two files:  A.txt and B.txt.

1)  Cmd T, then select A.txt.
2)  Work on A.txt, then `Cmd T`, split B.txt with `Ctrl V`.
3)  Work on B.txt, then need to switch back to A:  `Cmd T`, A.txt.  Currently Command T would either open A buffer to current split, or create a new split of A.  What I want is that the previously opened A buffer would be active again (the cursor would jump back to A) instead of a new split A  got created.

So essentially if a buffer has already been opened, resume to that split buffer.  Is there a tweak or shortcuts for this?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `:drop` or `:tab drop` instead of the default `:tabe` for opening files in the Command-T search buffer. This is configurable in your .gvimrc file:

```
function! CommandTAcceptSelectionTab()
  ruby $command_t.accept_selection :command => 'tab drop'
endfunction
```

This one bothered the heck out of me, too!

Answer (score 0):

There is a `'switchbuf'` option but that works only for `:sbuffer` and few more commands but not for `:split`, `:new` and others.

As far as I know it needs some vimscript woodoo, which I used some time ago but do not use anymore and just use `:sb` with completion.